# Adding complexity to an if then else loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro that works perfectly but that I now need to customize it and add complexity.

The macro is basically the following code repeated numerous times for a variety of ranges.

```
For i = 2 To n
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("J13:J19").Value
Next i
```

The logic/complexity that I need to add to this should go as follows:

if the sum of the range O13:O19 on sheet i is greater than zero, then the value of the range cells(13,i),cells 19,i) on this sheet are equal to the value of the range p13:p19 on sheet i.

If the value of the sum of range O13:O19 on sheet i is not greater than 0, then set the value of the target range equal to each cell in (range sheet(i).range("I13:I19")-sheet(i).range("K13:K19")*4).value

In simpler terms, if the sum of the range is 0, set the value of every cell in range A to the value of every cell in range b less the (value of every cell in range C * 4)...

```
   Sub Op_ex_analysis_macro()


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Control Panel"
Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 36
Range("A12").Value = "Property Code"
Range("A13:A16") = Sheets(2).Range("A13:A16").Value
Range("A17") = Sheets(2).Range("B17").Value
Range("A18") = Sheets(2).Range("A18").Value
Range("A19") = Sheets(2).Range("B19").Value
Range("A20:A29") = Sheets(2).Range("A21:A30").Value
Range("A30") = Sheets(2).Range("B31").Value
Range("A31") = Sheets(2).Range("A33").Value
Range("A32:A36") = Sheets(2).Range("A35:A39").Value
Range("A37:A38") = Sheets(2).Range("A41:A42").Value

Range("A40").Value = "Analyst"
Range("A41").Value = "Number of Units"
Range("A42").Value = "Asset Manager"
Range("A43").Value = "Tenancy"
Range("A44").Value = "Year Built/Type"
Range("A45").Value = "Management Company"
Range("A46").Value = "End of Compliance Year"
Range("A47").Value = "Property Name"
Range("A48").Value = "Number of Properties"
Range("A49").Value = "City"
Range("A50").Value = "State"


'Consolidate Property Codes
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To n
Z = Sheets(i).Range("P49").Value
Cells(12, i) = Z
Next i


'Consolidate rows 13-19

For i = 2 To n
Select Case Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("O13:O33"))
Case Is > 0
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("P13:P19").Value
Case Is = 0
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("I13:I19") - ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("K13:K19") * 4
End Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i think the best option is to use a Select case statement.

```
For i = 2 To n
Select Case Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("O13:O33"))
Case Is > 0
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("P13:P19").Value
Case Is < 0
Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(19, i)).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("I13:I19") - ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("K13:K19") * 4
End Select
Next i
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT** If ou want to account for whent it's "0" then just add a `Case Is 0`

Comment: But what if the value = 0 ?

Comment: Hey Joao, I'm trying your solution, but getting a syntax error that higlights row 2 of your code...

Comment: @AdamMcDermott Just edited the code, try it now please.

Comment: @braX added explanation above

Comment: Thanks @JoãoPedroDomingues , I'm getting sub or function not defined with the Sum highlighted.  Should it be worksheetfunction.sum...?

Comment: @AdamMcDermott actually is Application.Sum, changed it above. Sorry !

Comment: @JoãoPedroDomingues so close!.. "Subscript out of range" with the 2nd line highlighted... "select case application.sum(this...."

Comment: Hum that's a problem with your sheets. how many do you have ?

Comment: it's a dynamic number of sheets defined by: n = activeworkbook.sheets.count

Comment: the code works up through this piece we're discussion

Comment: Then why do you start with number 2 ?

Comment: I updated my original code to illustrate the code beginning to where we are...  The code begins by adding a summary worksheet to the front of the workbook (sheet 1), then starts populating based off of worksheets 2 through n

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to solve the problem through via a different route.

As A.S.H correctly noted above, you can't do arithmetic on VBA arrays.

The first half of my code was basically moving an array, as Scott Craner noted on a different page, which is simple.

Directing VBA to perform calculations requires the coder to send the formula through a range cell by cell.

Ultimately, the code that performed as required was as follows:

```
Dim rng As Range
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To n
        If Application.Sum(Sheets(i).Range("O13:O33")) > 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(13, i), .Cells(19, i)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("P13:P19").Value
        Else
            For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(13, i), .Cells(19, i))
                rng.Value = Sheets(i).Cells(rng.Row, "I") - (4 * Sheets(i).Cells(rng.Row, "K"))
            Next rng
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

If the condition of the first 1/2 of the if statement is met, then it's just set these values equal to those values.  If the condition is not met, then the Else statement directs Excel to move through the range performing the calculation as it goes.